# Why do we use functions that return by reference

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulties understanding method chaining.

Header file of the class `point3D.h`. You can disregard everything other than the setters:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

#ifndef UNTITLED_POINT3D_H
#define UNTITLED_POINT3D_H

class point3D
{
private:
    double coordX;
    double coordY;
    double coordZ;
    static int totalPointCount;
public:
    point3D();
    point3D(double x, double y, double z);

    point3D &setCoordX(double x);
    point3D &setCoordY(double y);
    point3D &setCoordZ(double z);

    double getCoordX() const;
    double getCoordY() const;
    double getCoordZ() const;
    static int getTotalPointCount();

    double calculateDistance(point3D p) const;

    point3D* test_function();
    point3D test_function2();
};

#endif //UNTITLED_POINT3D_H
```

And the implementations of the setters from `point3D.cpp`:

```cpp
point3D &point3D::setCoordX(double x )
{
    coordX = x;
    return *this;
}

point3D &point3D::setCoordY(double y )
{
    coordY = y;
    return *this;
}

point3D &point3D::setCoordZ(double z )
{
    coordZ = z;
    return *this;
}
```

And this is the `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "point3D.h"

int main()
{
    point3D p1(3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
    std::cout << "original values of p1:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordX: " << p1.getCoordX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordY: " << p1.getCoordY() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordZ: " << p1.getCoordZ() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    p1.setCoordX(6.0).setCoordY(7.0).setCoordZ(8.0);
    std::cout << "values of p1 after the setters:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordX: " << p1.getCoordX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordY: " << p1.getCoordY() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordZ: " << p1.getCoordZ() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works as intended so far, the output of the program is:

```
original values of p1:
coordX: 3
coordY: 4
coordZ: 5

values of p1 after the setters:
coordX: 6
coordY: 7
coordZ: 8

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My question is, why are we using the `&` operator in the declaration of the setters?

From what I understood so far, `this` is a pointer, and it holds the address of the object that is created. So, when we return `this` with the dereference operator (`return *this`), as we did in our setters, the value returned should be the type of `point3D`.

When I removed `&` from the setters declarations, this is what happened:

New setter functions:

```cpp
point3D point3D::setCoordX(double x ) //'&' removed
{
    coordX = x;
    return *this;
}

point3D point3D::setCoordY(double y ) //'&' removed
{
    coordY = y;
    return *this;
}

point3D point3D::setCoordZ(double z ) //'&' removed
{
    coordZ = z;
    return *this;
}
```

New `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "point3D.h"

int main()
{
    point3D p1(3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
    std::cout << "original values of p1:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordX: " << p1.getCoordX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordY: " << p1.getCoordY() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordZ: " << p1.getCoordZ() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    p1.setCoordX(6.0).setCoordY(7.0).setCoordZ(8.0); //setCoordY() and setCoordZ doesn't do anything
    std::cout << "values of p1 after the setters:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordX: " << p1.getCoordX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordY: " << p1.getCoordY() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordZ: " << p1.getCoordZ() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    p1 = p1.setCoordX(9.0).setCoordY(10.0).setCoordZ(11.0); // ?
    std::cout << "values of p1 after setters 2nd try:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordX: " << p1.getCoordX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordY: " << p1.getCoordY() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coordZ: " << p1.getCoordZ() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The new output of the program:

```
original values of p1:
coordX: 3
coordY: 4
coordZ: 5

values of p1 after the setters:
coordX: 6 //coordX is changed as intended
coordY: 4 //coordY remains unchanged
coordZ: 5 //coordZ remains unchanged

values of p1 after setters 2nd try:
coordX: 9  //changed as intended
coordY: 10 //changed as intended
coordZ: 11 //changed as intended

Process finished with exit code 0
```

With `&` removed from the `point3D`'s setters now, I can't method chain as I did before. Using the syntax that I used before (`p1.setCoordX().setCoordY().setCoordZ()`), only the `setCoordX()` function works, `setCoordY()` and `setCoordZ()` does nothing.

However, with this new weird syntax that I stumbled upon by chance (`p1 = p1.setCoordX().setCoordY().setCoordZ();`), it works. I don't understand how this happens, and the second declaration of setters makes more sense to me (without `&`).

My thought process is like this - `this` is a pointer, and I'm returning `this` with the dereference operator from my setters (`return *this`) so after calling `setCoordX()` the value returned is of type `point3D`, so I should be able to call the function `setCoordY()` using `.` operator and `setCoordZ()`.

Sorry if I misused some terminologies, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: *"you can disregard everything other than the setters."* -- or you could remove everything other than the setters from the *example* code. Perhaps even better: replace what was removed with a comment like `// And other functions in the real code.`. Keep in mind that the code only has to demonstrate the issue, not have full functionality. (The comment is to deal with people who might forget that and complain about missing pieces.) Just a way to make your question a bit easier to read.

Comment: Noted, sorry about that. This was my first time asking a question here thanks for providing a guidance on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward... with method-chaining, each method-call is called on (the object returned by the previous method call).  So in your original example:

```
p1.setCoordX(9.0).setCoordY(10.0).setCoordZ(11.0);
```

`setCoordX(9.0)` returns a reference to `p1`, and `setCoordY(10.0)` gets called on `p1` via that reference.  `setCoordY(10.0)` again returns a reference to `p1`, and `setCoordZ(11.0)` gets called on `p1` using that reference.  It's the same `point3D` object (`p1`) being modified by each of the method-calls.

When you change the methods to return type `point3D` instead of `point3D &`, the chained methods are no longer returning a *reference* to the existing `p1` object; rather they are returning a *copy* of the object they were called on.  This copy has no name (it's an anonymous/temporary object), and is therefore forever inaccessible to anything other than the next method-call in the chain, and it will be destroyed as soon as the next method-call has finished executing.

Modifying the temporary/anonymous `point3D` object isn't particularly useful, since what you (presumably) wanted to do was keep modifying the original (`p1`) object.  But it does explain the behavior you are seeing.

Note that in your final example (`p1 = p1.[...]`), you are "capturing" the final temporary/anonymous `point3D` object that was returned, by using the assignment-operator (`=`) to copy the last chained-method's returned anonymous/temporary-object back over to your original `p1` object, and that is why it gives you the behavior you intended.

To put it another way, your last example:

```
p1 = p1.setCoordX(9.0).setCoordY(10.0).setCoordZ(11.0)
```

... is a shorthand way to write something like this code:

```
{
   point3D temp1 = p1.setCoordX(9.0);     // sets p1 to (9,4,5) and returns a copy of it
   point3D temp2 = temp1.setCoordY(10.0); // sets temp1 to (9,10,5) and returns a copy of it
   point3D temp3 = temp2.setCoordZ(11.0); // sets temp2 to (9,10,11) and returns a copy of it
   p1 = temp3;   // sets (p1) equal to (temp3) aka (9,10,11)
}
```